# Does my Mobile App need a Certificate Authority(CA) for it's RestFul API? and what CA type (Public/Private)?

Tags: cordova, https, ssl-certificate

Our (Apache Cordova) app uses phone number for validation. We don't save any sensitive information about users other than: their displayed name, progress numbers, friends' list, ...etc

All of current requests (from client's mobile) to our API are using **http** and not **https**. Our back-end API is hosted on an AWS server without using any CA.

I'm not sure if, in our case, we need to use https or not. However, when I tried to create a CA through AWS ACM I was asked if it should be Private CA, or a Public CA! I opted for the public one but I'm very confused again.

Should I use Public CA or a Private CA for a mobile RestFul API server? Do I need https or it's overhead is not worth it in my situation??

Comment: When I say "sensitive" I meant "identifying" information. Users in our DataBase are basically anonymous phone numbers with progress data...

Answer (score 1):

In <del>2018</del> 2019, **https** should be the *default* choice for any API over *http*, because data security should be always *by design*.

> We don't save any sensitive information about users other than: their displayed name, progress numbers, friends' list, ...etc

Phone numbers with a friends list are potentially sensitive data.

## [Certificate Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority)

> In cryptography, a certificate authority or certification authority (CA) is an entity that issues digital certificates. A digital certificate certifies the ownership of a public key by the named subject of the certificate. This allows others (relying parties) to rely upon signatures or on assertions made about the private key that corresponds to the certified public key. A CA acts as a trusted third party—trusted both by the subject (owner) of the certificate and by the party relying upon the certificate. (from Wikipedia)

I think that is better for you to get a SSL certificate from one of the many vendor available online (AWS ACM, Cloudflare, ...) using a [public CA](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shreyasgowda/2017/08/18/public-certificates-vs-private-certificates-vs-self-signed-certificates/). This is a must have in public available services because you need that every browser/client can recognize your https certificate as valid, and this is done by checking its sign against a built-in set of (public) CA data. Note that this is a very easy representation of the real https security mechanism, so please look for more information in the Internet.

### Let's encrypt

Another free solution is to use [Let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to generate a free SSL certificate. Let's encrypt is a public CA that provides SSL certificates for free and you have many tools to manage them automatically.

### More on REST security

I suggest you to also check the [OWASP REST Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet) for more useful information about REST API.